# Sql Server Session Context Limit

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, dapper

We are having issues setting and clearing out session context values.

We receive the following error: 
`The value was not set for key X because the total size of keys and values in the session context would exceed the 1 MB limit`

We are using asp.net core and dapper for our data access.

When opening a connection we execute `sp_set_session_context` and send 4 keys. 3 which are integers and 1 which is a string.

In testing the string is null and the integers are less than 10.

After executing a sql command we then set the session context values to null, close, and dispose of the connection.

We are using the following query to view memory usage:
`SELECT SUM([pages_kb]) 
FROM [sys].[dm_os_memory_cache_counters]
WHERE [type] = 'CACHESTORE_SESSION_CONTEXT'`

That query has yet to exceed 1MB.

Does anyone know why we are receiving this error?

Comment: have you read the [MSDN Documentation- sp_set_session_context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql) about the particular function

Comment: @MethodMan Yes I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known bug, which has been fixed in SQL Server 2016 and 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089324). The following script will reliably reproduce it:

```
bool unset = true;
using (var command = new SqlCommand()) {
  command.CommandText = "sp_set_session_context";
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  command.Parameters.Add("@key", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
  command.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Variant, -1);
  for (int cycles = 0; cycles != 10; ++cycles) { 
    ++cycles;
    using (var connection = 
      new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSqlLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI")
    ) {
      connection.Open();
      // Set as many values as we can
      int keys = 0;
      while (true) {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters["@key"].Value = keys.ToString();
        command.Parameters["@value"].Value = new String(' ', 8000);
        try {
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          ++keys;
        } catch (SqlException e) {
          Console.WriteLine("Failed setting at {0}: {1}", keys, e.Message);
          break;
        }
      }
      if (unset) {
        // Now unset them
        for (; keys >= 0; --keys) {
          command.Connection = connection;
          command.Parameters["@key"].Value = keys.ToString();
          command.Parameters["@value"].Value = DBNull.Value;
          try {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          } catch (SqlException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed unsetting at {0}: {1}", keys, e.Message);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> Failed setting at 125: The value was not set for key '125' because the total size of keys and values in the session context would exceed the 1 MB limit.
>   Failed setting at 120: The value was not set for key '120' because the total size of keys and values in the session context would exceed the 1 MB limit.
>   Failed setting at 115: The value was not set for key '115' because the total size of keys and values in the session context would exceed the 1 MB limit.
>   Failed setting at 110: The value was not set for key '110' because the total size of keys and values in the session context would exceed the 1 MB limit.
>   Failed setting at 105: The value was not set for key '105' because the total size of keys and values in the session context would exceed the 1 MB limit.

The available context size decreases with every cycle. If continued for long enough, it will drop to some minimal value (not necessarily 0). At this point, querying `sys.dm_os_memory_cache_counters` shows that there is far less than 1 MB in use, but even so, no more session context can be set.

This bug has been [fixed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089324) in SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU8 and SQL Server 2017 CU6. (The fix mentions clearing up the memory issue if you use a `NULL` value for the *key* parameter, but using a `NULL` value for the key isn't allowed in the first place and will produce an error even in older versions. According to my tests it's been fixed for unsetting *values*.)

For prior versions, there are at least two workarounds:

- don't set the values to `NULL` when you're done, leave the engine to clear them out. In the above script, if you set `unset` to `false`, you will observe no session context getting leaked.
- use a non-`NULL` sentinel value to mark "removed" values, like an empty string.

Comment: Thanks so much for reporting that. As of today, it's not fixed. My workaround is to store an invalid value instead of null.